# NixOS: use GHC ver 7.8.3 system wide

Tags: haskell, overriding, default, ghc, nixos

I want to have GHC 7.8.3 to be default system wide Haskell compiler, and I do not want to install entire platform; here is piece of my `configurarion.nix` file:

```nix
{
    environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [ 
        haskellPackages_ghc783_profiling.alex
        haskellPackages_ghc783_profiling.happy 
        # ghc.ghc783 -- not sure about this one
        haskellPackages_ghc783_profiling.ghc
        haskellPackages_ghc783_profiling.cabalInstall
    ];
}
```

However, ver 7.6.3 show by default and I can't imagine where it comes from...

```
$ ghc --verion
$ The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
```

I've found some tips on [Wiki pages](https://nixos.org/wiki/Haskell):

```nix
pkgs : {
   packageOverrides = self : rec {
     hsEnv = self.haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (self : [
         self.haskellPlatform
         # add more packages here
         #
         #   I tried to replace `self.haskellPlatform`
         #   with `self:ghc783`, 
         #   with `self:haskellPackages.ghc_783_profiling.ghc`, and
         #   with `self:ghc`, but all that produces errors.
     ]);
   };
 }
```

So, what is the right way to make version 7.8.3 to be default?

Comment: If you want to know from where `7.6.3` comes, you can use `which` command to find out it's path.

Comment: I'm familiar with `which`, I meant that it is not listed in my configuration, but actually present in system (:

Answer (score 1):

To use a specific GHC version system wide I use a module [like this one:](https://github.com/coreyoconnor/nix_configs/blob/master/haskell-dev.nix)

Use `nixpkgs.config.packageOverrides` to rename `haskellPackages` to the desired version and add a haskell environment:

```
nixpkgs.config.cabal.libraryProfiling = true;
nixpkgs.config.packageOverrides = in_pkgs : rec
  { 
    haskellPackages = in_pkgs.haskellPackages_ghc784_profiling;
    hsEnv = in_pkgs.haskellPackages_ghc784_profiling.ghcWithPackages hsPkgs;
  }
```

Define `hsPkgs` to be a package list constructor:

Add the `hsEnv` to the `environment.systemPackages`:

```
environment.systemPackages = [ hsEnv ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you installed it in your user nix env? Try `nix-env -q`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, my NixOS vm crashed (because of host partition issue), I'll be able create new one in few days and recheck. Fortunatelly, I have my configs recovered.

Comment: Hmmm. With minimal clean installation I can't reproduse this issue anymore.